# How to load data from Firestore in ReactJS shopping cart instead of LocalStroage

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, react-context

My cart context is below where I am setting the data in localstorage if cart content changes and displaying that data using getLocalData() function on cart load

```
const getLocalData = () => {
   const item = localStorage.getItem("cartItem");
   const parsedData = JSON.parse(item);
   if (!Array.isArray(parsedData)) return [];
   return parsedData;
};

const initialState = {
   cart: getLocalData(),
   cartLoading: true,
   cartError: null,
   totalPrice: 0,
   totalAmount: 0,
   deliveryFee: 6.12,
};
const CartProvider = ({ children }) => {
   const { user, cart } = useAuthContext();
       const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
   const [fetchCart, setFetchCart] = useState([]);
   
   const addToCart = (product) => {
       dispatch({ type: "ADD_TO_CART", payload: product });
   };

       //using this function to add cart data in firestore collections
    const getCartData = async () => {
       try {
           const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "cart"), {
               cart: state.cart,
           });
           console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
       } catch (e) {
           console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
       }
   };

       //using this function to fetch the data from firestore and set it to cart
   const datas = async (users) => {
       const docRef = collection(db, "cart");
       const snapshot = await getDocs(docRef);
       const data = snapshot.docs.map((x) => x.data().cart);
       //console.log(data);
       //console.log(data[data.length - 1]);
       setFetchCart(data[data.length - 1]);
   };
    
   useEffect(() => {
       dispatch({ type: "TOTAL_CART_PRICE_AMOUNT" });
       //localStorage.setItem("cartItem", JSON.stringify(state.cart));
       datas().then(() => dispatch({ type: "ADD_FROM_FIREBASE", payload: fetchCart }));
       getCartData();
   }, [state.cart]);

   return (
       <CartContext.Provider value={{ ...state, addToCart, removeCart, setDecrease, setIncrease }}>
           {children}
       </CartContext.Provider>
   );
};
```

My cart reducer

```
const CartReducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
    switch (type) {
        case "ADD_FROM_FIREBASE":
            console.log(payload);
            return {
                ...state,
                cart: payload,
            };
        case "ADD_TO_CART":
            const { id, title, price, stock, description, images, discountPercentage, brand } = payload;

            let existingProduct = state.cart.find((cart) => cart.id === id);
            if (existingProduct) {
                let updatedProduct = state.cart.map((currElem) => {
                    if (currElem.id === id) {
                        let newAmount = currElem.amount + 1;
                        if (currElem.amount >= stock) {
                            newAmount = currElem.stock;
                        }

                        return {
                            ...currElem,
                            amount: newAmount,
                        };
                    } else {
                        return {
                            ...currElem,
                        };
                    }
                });

                return {
                    ...state,
                    cart: updatedProduct,
                };
            } else {
                let amount = 1;
                let cartProduct = {
                    title,
                    price,
                    stock,
                    description,
                    images,
                    id,
                    discountPercentage,
                    brand,
                    amount,
                };
                return {
                    cart: [...state.cart, cartProduct],
                };
            }

        case "REMOVE_CART":
            return {
                ...state,
                cart: state.cart.filter((cart) => cart.id != payload),
            };

        case "TOTAL_CART_PRICE_AMOUNT":
            const { totalPrice, totalAmount } = state.cart.reduce(
                (acc, curr) => {
                    let { price, amount } = curr;

                    acc.totalAmount += amount;
                    acc.totalPrice += price * amount;
                    return acc;
                },
                { totalPrice: 0, totalAmount: 0 }
            );
            return {
                ...state,
                totalAmount,
                totalPrice,
            };

        default:
            return {
                ...state,
            };
    }
};
```

I tried to add cartData in firestore using getCartData() function which is working correctly. But when I am trying to read data from firestore and set its value to cart, it is not working.
I wants functionality where, logged in user when adds something to cart, its data should get updated in firestore collections db and then fetch that data from firestore and display data in cart. It should be different for different users.

Till now I have implemented the functionality of adding cart data in localStorage and displayin that data from localStorage. But using localStorage,the same cart data is displayed to different logged in users.

when I uses `datas().then(()=> ...)` in useEffect it reads data but since it is fecthing data and updating fetchCart, it goes into infinite rendering loop.

So any help would be appreciated in this matter

Comment: Can you also share your `reducer` function by editing the question as we didn't know if `state.cart` updated in the reducer as well.
And it is best practice to designate user data with his `user.uid` so we can get his related data based on querying `user.uid` in the Firestore cart collection. Something like `const docRef = collection(db, "cart").where("userId", "==", user.uid);`

Comment: Yes thanks for the suggestion. I had previously used user.email to set data in firestore but I removed it later. But you said it right to use user.uid as it is unique and more secure. I have added my cart reducer in the question